# Port is already in use - for any port on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, express

So recently I got a Macbook and I have cloned my project on it which is a MERN stack application. The port in my `.env` is 5000. When I attempt to start up the server I get the error that the port is already in use.

I figured "hmm ok, i'll change it to 5100". That worked, but only for that time, the next time I tried to run it i got the same error for port 5100.

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Check the process Id

```
lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep 5000
```

Check the process name

```
  ps -Ao user,pid,command | grep -v grep | grep <<pid>>
```

which will output something similar to this, which means your mac OS is utilising port 5000

```
622 /System/Library/CoreServices/ControlCenter.app/Contents/MacOS/ControlCenter
```

This is because new AirPlay functionality in mac Monterey version is utilising port 5000. To disable that you can

```
go to system preferences -> search for sharing -> untick AirPlay Receiver in left side panel
```

Comment: Is there also a way to disable it via console?

Comment: Great solution! Was so perplexed why 5000 was staying in use! This was it!

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
netstat -anvp tcp | awk 'NR<3 || /LISTEN/'
```

(credits: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117648)

and use

```
ps aux PID
```

to see the correspoding proccess. (PID is number from PID columen, ofc.)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the new AirPlay functionality on Monterrey Os.
Control Center stops listening to those ports when you turn off “AirPlay Receiver”.

In the “Sharing” System Preference, so uncheck airplay receiver:
[image]

After that you must kill the process that take the 500 port

```
lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep 5000
```

That show you which process to kill

Then, you can use the port 5000 again.